# Semantic UI React - How to prevent scrolling on button press for required input in form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm attempting to prevent the page from scrolling whenever a button is pressed in a form with a required input. [Here is an example of what I am referring to.](https://codesandbox.io/s/wkpp7k6z05)

To see what I mean, scroll the viewer on the right all the way down and press the button, it should scroll the view all the way up to the required input field.

I need a way to prevent this, I've attempted adding listeners for event such as `onScroll` or `onClick`. The closest to a solution I have found is to add a listener on the document for the `scroll` event and stop propagation of the event, however this prevents normal scrolling from the user as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms?rq=1)

Adding `type='button'` to the button prevents the behavior.

Sample shown [here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/nwo19oxyx4)